# Corona sdk minimum opengl version warning

Tags: opengl, lua, coronasdk

This is my first time with corona sdk when i try to open project with simulator it gives me this warning and not allow to run any lua project it looks like this

[image]

Previously it was given error that your machine opengl version is 1.1.0 and Minimum required version is 1.2. So i updated it now it gives me warning again and asking for 2.1.

Comment: Update your graphics drivers.

Comment: i have updated driver too

Comment: Describe how you upgraded, and how you determined what version of opengl you have installed

Comment: i checked the display card model and i downloaded it drivers from intel site. Warning massage says that your opengl version is 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Staring with Corona SDK build 2013.2000 or later, the minimum OpenGL was updated to handle the features of the new Graphics 2.0 engine.  Build 1262 is the last Graphics 1.0 build, however, due to new requirements from both Apple and Google, that build will not be able to deploy apps any longer to those stores.  You probably could still deploy to Amazon or Barnes & Noble with that build.

Just as an FYI, for Google, if you intend to do anything with ads, you must use the latest public build 2393 or a daily build after 2264.